# Set Due Date using a Workflow for a date 2 days after the item was created

Tags: date-time

Running into trouble using Designer.  I need my workflow to set the due date for 2 days in the future but it will only let me set today's date or a specific date as the value.

Comment: Looked around and found this, workflow actions and variables is the answer... duhh!!!

Option #4
http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sample-sharepoint-workflows/4-ways-set-date-value-sharepoint-designer-workflow.htm

Comment: Yes, you have to calculate it and set it to the variable, put that as your answer so it can be accepted.